# Argument of type '<<custom component name>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<<custom component name>>'

Tags: typescript, bootstrap-modal, angular7

This is the error I'm getting. I know there is a type parameters mismatch somehow, but I can't figure out where in the stack it's happening.

```
Argument of type 'ModalUserInfoComponent' is not assignable to 
parameter of type 'Type<ModalUserInfoComponent>'.
Type 'ModalUserInfoComponent' is missing the following properties from 
type 'Type<ModalUserInfoComponent>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 
5 more.
```

I've got a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bs-modal-service) set up that shows the issue. The functionality only partially works (I'm assuming as a result of not passing the necessary form builder data around because this issue is blocking it somehow).

You'll notice in the stackblitz that the modal is only passing back the first and last name, the rest are absent.

There's another error as well, and I'm pretty sure it's related, but I haven't looked into it yet.

```
Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has 
changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'form: undefined'. 
Current value: 'form: [object Object]'. It seems like the view has been 
created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has 
it been created in a change detection hook ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

OK--the fix for this issue was:

```
public contentComponent: Type<ModalVariants>;
```

Instead of:

```
public contentComponent: <ModalVariants>;
```

which is what I had.